# Swift4: New Codable protocol issue

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift4, codable

I am trying to use new Codable protocol in my application, but I can not get the conversation from JSON to my object. Here what I have:

```
struct LoginCodableEntity: Codable {
    let authToken: String? = ""
    let status: String? = ""
    let errorMessage: String? = ""
    let errorCode: Int?


    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case errorMessage = "message"
        case authToken = "auth_token"
        case errorCode = "code"
    }
}
Alamofire.request(API.login).responseJSON { (response) in
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let json = try decoder.decode(LoginCodableEntity.self, from: response.data!)
                    print("JSON: \(json)")



             } catch let err {
                    print("Err", err)
                }

            }
```

I got response from my API with data and json var got object cast, but fields in it are empty:

```
JSON: LoginCodableEntity(authToken: Optional(""), status: Optional(""), errorMessage: Optional(""), errorCode: Optional(800))
```

I made this example base on [this tutorial](https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1), but seems like something wrong with this implementations
The returned JSON is looks like:

```
JSON: Optional({
    code = 910;
    message = "Credentials denied";
    status = error;
})
```

Comment: Last time I checked, Alamofire was not ready for Codable protocol. They are planning to implement it in the version 5. You can test it download the `alamofire5` branch and using the `responseJSONDecodable` method, instead of current `responseJSON`

Comment: Pretty bad tutorial. If you declare everything as optional you get no output and you have no idea why. Remove all `? = ""` and handle the error. It would be helpful to add the relevant part of the JSON to the question.

Comment: Could you show us the JSON you get in the response?

Comment: @andlin I added JSON

Comment: @MarcoPace I saw this new feature, but the problem is not in Alamofire I think, because JSONDecoder is looking for Data object in its function and Alamofire has it inside its implementation

Comment: @vadian Same result without non-optional values in struct :( Could you provide better tutorial from your POV

Comment: Can't be. You should get an error

Comment: You cannot reassign constants. Remove the default values.

Comment: @Sulthan Man you are right!!! You can post your answer I will accept it. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the default values from the constants:

```
let authToken: String?
let status: String?
let errorMessage: String?
let errorCode: Int?
```

Constants cannot be reassigned. Once you give them a default value, they cannot be assigned again during parsing.